# Positioning Div's

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm working with http://jsfiddle.net/ngZdg/

Ultimately, I'm trying to get a parallax website going, but i'm struggling with initial layout issues. I'm trying to get the following layout:

```
-------------------------------------
|                                    |
|                                    |
|           ______  ______           |
|           |       |     |          |
|           |       |     |          |
|           ______  ______           |
|                   |     |          |
|                   |     |          |
|                   ______           |
|                                    |
-------------------------------------
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: which box should be 1_1, 1_2, 1_3 from your code?

Answer (score 1):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ngZdg/16/):

```
@charset"utf-8";
 #main {
    background-color:pink;
    width:1280px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
#chapter1 {
    background: blue;
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
}
#chapter1_1 {
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    left:100px;
    top:50px;
    position:absolute;    
}
#chapter1_2 {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    left:205px;
    top:50px;
    position:absolute;
}
#chapter1_3 {
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    top:155px;
    left:205px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

You also need to close your `<DIV>` tags.

```
<div class="whatever" />
```

is not correct, it needs to be

```
<div class="whatever"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you closed your divs was not closing them in the fiddle. This creates something similar to your diagram.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="chapter1">
        <div id="chapter1_1"></div>
        <div id="chapter1_2"></div>
        <div id="chapter1_3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
} 
#main {
    background-color:#00FF00;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-640px;*/
}
#chapter1 {
    background: blue;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    width:100%
}
#chapter1_1,
#chapter1_2,
#chapter1_3 {
    height:20%;
    width:20%;
    position:absolute;
}
#chapter1_1 {
    background-color:red;
    top:10%;
    left:30%;    
}
#chapter1_2 {
    background-color:yellow;
    left:50%;
    top:10%;
}
#chapter1_3 {
    background-color:green;
    top:30%;
    left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle, with the background absolute,and other div are relative in positioning

```
Please refer link http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/ngZdg/19/
```

the CSS is like this

```
@charset"utf-8";
 #main {
    background:pink;
    width:1280px;
    height:900px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#chapter1 {
    margin:100px auto 100px auto;
    background: blue;
    height:500px;
    width:800px;
    padding:100px;
}
#chapter1_1, #chapter1_2, #chapter1_3 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
}
#chapter1_1 {
    background-color:red;
    left:100px;
}
#chapter1_2 {
    background-color:yellow;
    left:100px;
}
#chapter1_3 {
    clear:both;// to clear the float to next line.
    background-color:green;
    left:300px;
}
```

I am sure this will do. :)